# C - huge arrays - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, arrays

I'm getting the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Either of these approaches work if loops = 207500 or smaller.  However if I increase this (e.g. 2100000) I get the error

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
  long i;
  long loops;

  loops = 2075000; // works
  loops = 2100000; // Segmentation fault (core dumped)

  if (1) {       
    int arr[loops]; // stack array
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
      arr[i] = 3;
    }
  }

  if (1) {
    int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * loops); // heap array
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
      arr[i] = 3;
    }
  }

}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via Virtual box with 8gb ram allocated

Comment: What you're doing is a classic recipe for producing stack overflow!

Comment: In OS, there is a ulimit for stack size. In linux, the defaulit is 8192K.

You program will use stack: 2100000*4 bytes / 1024 bytes= 8203K is larger than default size.

How to get in linux:

    ulimit 
    -s: stack size (kbytes)        8192

Comment: May I suggest a few improvements in the code?
The lines `if (1)` have absolutely no meaning.
Also, some C compilers won't let you initialize an array using a varible: `int arr[loops];` won't always compile.

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing your stack, the stack space is very limited compared to the heap. You can find typical stack sizes listed [Stack Overflow Problems article](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt):

```
platform    default size       
=====================================
SunOS/Solaris  8172K bytes
Linux          8172K bytes
Windows        1024K bytes
cygwin         2048K bytes
```

The alternative would be to dynamically allocate your array via `malloc` which would use the much more plentiful heap.